# Don't stop printf at null termination (\0)

Tags: c, printf

printf stops printing at the first \0 it meets.

Is there a way to force it to continue, for example if my string contains more characters after \0.

Comment: `if my string contains more characters after \0.`..then your input is erroneous.

Comment: So how does it decide when to stop printing?

Comment: Uugh, If that data beyond the first zero really is owned by you then substitute another character for it.

Comment: if a string has more info after the `\0`, what's the point of having a `\0`?

Comment: "*....  if my string contains more characters after \0.*" it such characters are also `0`-terminated you do not have one string but "*more*" strings.

Comment: A "string with embedded NULs" is not really a string in the sense of `<string.h>` and `<stdio.h>` functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the length of your string as `n` characters, you can output it using `fwrite`:

```
if (n && fwrite(str, 1, n, stdout) != n) {
    /* Error handling. */
}
```

Comment: Just a q sir, `printf()` family is for formatted o/p, isn't it? Can `fwrite()` be a good substitute?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, but formatted output is for textual data. Textual data does not contain null characters.

Comment: Is it really an error to want to print zero characters?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `printf("%s", ...)` is actually pretty silly if you know the length of the string, because you're forcing both dynamic format string parsing and searching for the end, when neither are needed.

Comment: @Hurkyl Not if your data is not textual. If your data is textual, then yes, having zero characters is an error.

Answer (score 3):

No, not directly.

What you can do is put it in a loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char test[] = "one\0two\0three\0four\0"; /* double NUL to terminate data */
    char *ptr = test;
    do {
        ptr += printf("%s\n", ptr); /* add string size + 1 (extra 1 from '\n') */
    } while (*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `putchar`:

```
char *buffer = "1234\0ABCD\0hello";
char *s = buffer;
int n = 6;

while (n--)
    putchar(*s++);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the count of null terminated strings to display:

```
size_t str_count; // Count of '\0' in my_str
const char * my_str; // Points on contiguous Null terminated strings

for(size_t i=0; i<str_count; i++)
{
    printf("%s", my_str);
    my_str += 1 + strlen(my_str); // "+1" to skip the `\0`
}
```